# Views Filters: show published items from the last week or minimum number of items

Tags: views

The homepage on our local newswebsite "Zee-Online" has a view that shows al published content from the last week. How can i change this, to show at least a fixed number of items?

I want a view that gives me all the nodes from the last week OR at least 12 items (if the first filter-criteria doesn't result in at least 12 items)

Comment: items per page could set a maximum. You might have to use php for the 'or' condition.

Comment: I don't want a maximum! If there are less then 12 items published in the last week, it should display older items to get the minimum of twelve.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to create a Views filter using an "OR" relationship, you might want to consider module [Views Contextual Filters OR](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_contextual_filters_or) (which only has a dev version today). Excerpt from its project page:

> ... provides a views plugin which modify query to support OR conditions for contextual filters.

Does this help?

Comment: There's an OR relationship in the views module, but i can't configure a way to display the 12 most recent items. (and second clausule is OR published in the last week). Now i solved the problem using an Attachment in the view. We use the masonry views module on our page. It's almost what i want, but not perfect. The items in the attachment doesn't align with the masonry layout in the view.... (www.zee-online.be) (you can see where the attachment starts)

Comment: There's another problem: There are duplicate results in the page and attachment, but the query-settings => distinct doesn't solve the problem?